# How to get Mean and Standard deviation from a Frequency Distribution table

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe

I have a list of tuples `[(val1, freq1), (val2, freq2) .... (valn, freqn)]`. I need to get measures of central tendencies (mean, median ) and measures of deviation (variance , std) for the above data.I would also like to plot a boxplot for the values.

I see that numpy arrays have direct methods for getting mean / median and standard deviation (or variance) from list of values.

Does numpy (or any other well-known library) have a direct means to operate on such a frequency distribution table ?

Also: What is the best way to programmatically expand the above list of tuples to one list?  (e.g if freq dist is `[(1,3) , (50,2)]`, best way to get a list `[1,1,1,50,50]` to use `np.mean([1,1,1,50,50])`)?

I see a custom function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689099/using-describe-with-weighted-data), but I would like to use a standard implementation if possible.

Comment: @ayhan I have attributed your solution to the description ... and clarified what I am looking for . Can you remove the duplicate tag ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, I'd change that messy list into two `numpy` arrays like @user8153 did:

```
val, freq = np.array(list_tuples).T
```

Then you can reconstruct the array (using `np.repeat` prevent looping):

```
data = np.repeat(val, freq)
```

And use [`numpy` statistical functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.statistics.html) on your `data` array.

---

If that causes memory errors (or you just want to squeeze out as much performance as possible), you can also use some purpose-built functions:

```
def mean_(val, freq):
    return np.average(val, weights = freq)

def median_(val, freq):
    ord = np.argsort(val)
    cdf = np.cumsum(freq[ord])
    return val[ord][np.searchsorted(cdf, cdf[-1] // 2)]

def mode_(val, freq): #in the strictest sense, assuming unique mode
    return val[np.argmax(freq)]

def var_(val, freq):
    avg = mean_(val, freq)
    dev = freq * (val - avg) ** 2
    return dev.sum() / (freq.sum() - 1)

def std_(val, freq):
    return np.sqrt(var_(val, freq))
```

Comment: Error at "return dev.sum() / (freq.sum() - 1) " in function "var_" , 'Float64Index' object has no attribute 'sum'

Comment: @ppau2004 I'm sure `pandas` has its own, much better-implemented versions of these.  Probably want to make a question asking how if you can't find it (I'm not a `pandas` expert but there are plenty around here)

Comment: Actually, @AditjaRajgor below has a `pandas` answer

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
```

**Frequency Distributed Data**

```
    class   freq
0   60-65   3
1   65-70   150
2   70-75   335
3   75-80   135
4   80-85   4
```

Create Middle point column for classes

```
df[['Upper','Lower']]=df['class'].str.split('-',expand=True)
df['Xi']=(df['Upper'].astype(float)+df['Lower'].astype(float))/2
df.drop(['Upper','Lower'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Therefore

```
    class   freq  Xi
0   60-65   3     62.5
1   65-70   150   67.5
2   70-75   335   72.5
3   75-80   135   77.5
4   80-85   4     82.5
```

**Mean**

```
mean = np.average(df['Xi'], weights=df['freq'])
mean
72.396331738437
```

**Standard Deviation**

```
std = np.sqrt(np.average((df['Xi']-mean)**2,weights=df['freq']))
std
3.5311919641103877
```

Comment: Thank you @Adita Rajgor. I fail to execute the median successfully. Can you point me in the right direction please? [-> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77092248/median-from-frequency-table-with-df-apply)]

Answer (score 3):

- To convert the (value, frequency) list to a list of values:

  ```
  freqdist =  [(1,3), (50,2)]
  sum(([val,]*freq for val, freq in freqdist), [])
  ```

  gives

  ```
  [1, 1, 1, 50, 50]
  ```
- To compute the mean you can avoid the building of the list of values by using `np.average` which takes a `weights` argument:

  ```
  vals, freqs = np.array(freqdist).T
  np.average(vals, weights = freqs)
  ```

  gives 20.6 as you would expect. I don't think this works for the mean, variance, or standard deviation, though.