# Getting descriptive statistics with (analytic) weighting using describe() in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, statistics

I was trying to translate code from Stata to Python

The original code in Stata:

```
by year, sort : summarize age [aweight = wt]
```

Normally a simply `describe()` function will do

```
dataframe.groupby("year")["age"].describe()
```

But I could not find a way to translate the `aweight` option into the language of python i.e. to give descriptive statistics of a dataset under analytic/ variance weighting.

codes to generate the dataset in python:

```
dataframe = {'year': [2016,2016,2020, 2020], 'age': [41,65, 35,28], 'wt':[ 1.2, 0.7,0.8,1.5]}
```

if I run `by year, sort : summarize age [aweight = wt]` on stata,

the outcome is : mean =49.842 and SD = 16.37

What should I do to get the same outcome in Python?

Comment: Try to give a simple minimum working example, specifying some exact input and the desired output.

Comment: i haven't used stata in a while...but shouldn't `by year, sort: summarize age  [aweight=wt]` compute means and std. deviations for each year? So you should have a mean and std. deviation for each year, in your case, 2016 and 2020?

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote a function that performs the same thing as `describe` except taking a weight argument. I tested it on the small dataframe you provided, but haven't gone into too much detail. I tried not to use `.apply` in case you have a large dataframe, though I didn't run a bench mark to see if my approach would be faster/less memory intensive than writing a function to do a weighted describe for each `by` group and then using `apply` to apply that to each `by` group in the dataframe. That would probably be easiest.

Counts, min and max can be taken without regard to weighting. Then I did simple weighted mean and std. deviation--from formula for unbiased variance. I included an option for frequency weighting, which should just effect the sample size used to adjust the variance to the unbiased estimator. Frequency weights should use the sum of the weights as the sample size, otherwise, uses the count in the data. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844024/weighted-percentile-using-numpy) to help get weighted percentiles.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2016,2016,2020, 2020], 
                        'age': [41,65, 35,28], 'wt':[ 1.2, 0.7,0.8,1.5]})
df
   year  age   wt
0  2016   41  1.2
1  2016   65  0.7
2  2020   35  0.8
3  2020   28  1.5
```

Then I define the  function below.

```
def weighted_groupby_describe(df, col, by, wt, frequency=False):
    '''
    df : dataframe
    col : column for which you want statistics, must be single column
    by : groupby column(s)
    wt : column to use for weights
    frequency : if True, use sample size as sum of weights (only effects degrees
    of freedom correction for unbiased variance)
    '''
    
    if isinstance(by, list):
        df = df.sort_values(by+[col])
    else:
        df = df.sort_values([by] + [col])
    
    newcols = ['gb_weights', 'col_weighted', 'col_mean', 
        'col_sqdiff', 'col_sqdiff_weighted', 'gb_weights_cumsum', 'ngroup']
    assert all([c not in df.columns for c in newcols])
    
    df['gb_weights'] = df[wt]/df.groupby(by)[wt].transform('sum')
    
    df['gb_weights_cumsum'] = df.groupby(by)['gb_weights'].cumsum()
    
    df['col_weighted'] = df.eval('{}*gb_weights'.format(col))
    
    df['col_mean'] = df.groupby(by)['col_weighted'].transform('sum')
    
    df['col_sqdiff'] = df.eval('({}-col_mean)**2'.format(col))
    df['col_sqdiff_weighted'] = df.eval('col_sqdiff*gb_weights')
    
    wstd = df.groupby(by)['col_sqdiff_weighted'].sum()**(0.5)
    wstd.name = 'std'
    
    wmean = df.groupby(by)['col_weighted'].sum()
    wmean.name = 'mean'
    
    df['ngroup'] = df.groupby(by).ngroup()
    quantiles = np.array([0.25, 0.5, 0.75])
    weighted_quantiles = df['gb_weights_cumsum'] - 0.5*df['gb_weights'] + df['ngroup']
    ngroups = df['ngroup'].max()+1
    x = np.hstack([quantiles+i for i in range(ngroups)])
    quantvals = np.interp(x, weighted_quantiles, df[col])
    quantvals = np.reshape(quantvals, (ngroups, -1))
    
    other = df.groupby(by)[col].agg(['min', 'max', 'count'])
    
    stats = pd.concat([wmean, wstd, other], axis=1, sort=False)
    
    stats['25%'] = quantvals[:, 0]
    stats['50%'] = quantvals[:, 1]
    stats['75%'] = quantvals[:, 2]
    
    colorder = ['count', 'mean', 'std', 'min', '25%', '50%', '75%', 'max']
    stats = stats[colorder]
    
    if frequency:
        sizes = df.groupby(by)[wt].sum()
    else:
        sizes = stats['count']
    
    stats['weight'] = sizes
    
    # use the "sample size" (weight) to obtain std. deviation from unbiased
    # variance
    stats['std'] = stats.eval('((std**2)*(weight/(weight-1)))**(1/2)')
    
    return stats
```

And test it out.

```
weighted_groupby_describe(df, 'age', 'year', 'wt')
      count       mean        std  min  ...        50%        75%  max  weight
year                                    ...                                   
2016      2  49.842105  16.372398   41  ...  49.842105  61.842105   65       2
2020      2  30.434783   4.714936   28  ...  30.434783  33.934783   35       2
```

Compare this to the output without the weights.

```
df.groupby('year')['age'].describe()
      count  mean        std   min    25%   50%    75%   max
year                                                        
2016    2.0  53.0  16.970563  41.0  47.00  53.0  59.00  65.0
2020    2.0  31.5   4.949747  28.0  29.75  31.5  33.25  35.0
```

Comment: Do you have any questions/comments on the solution provided? Are you looking for something else? If so, I can help resolve them. Otherwise, if the question was answered satisfactorily you can accept the answer.