# Numpy: Difference between dot(a,b) and (a*b).sum()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, precision, floating-accuracy

For 1-D numpy arrays, this two expressions should yield the same result (theorically):

```
(a*b).sum()/a.sum()
dot(a, b)/a.sum()
```

The latter uses `dot()` and is faster. But which one is more accurate? Why?

Some context follows.

I wanted to compute the weighted variance of a sample using numpy. 
I found the `dot()` expression in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413522/weighted-standard-deviation-in-numpy), with a comment stating that it should be more accurate. However no explanation is given there.

Comment: This is a weighted average, right? You might just want to just use [`np.average`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html).

Comment: I think the part about "numerically precise" was referring to subtracting out the average from the values, rather than using `dot`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Numpy dot is one of the routines that calls the BLAS library that you link on compile (or builds its own). The importance of this is the BLAS library can make use of Multiply–accumulate operations (usually Fused-Multiply Add) which limit the number of roundings that the computation performs.

Take the following:

```
>>> a=np.ones(1000,dtype=np.float128)+1E-14 
>>> (a*a).sum()  
1000.0000000000199948
>>> np.dot(a,a)
1000.0000000000199948
```

Not exact, but close enough.

```
>>> a=np.ones(1000,dtype=np.float64)+1E-14
>>> np.dot(a,a)
1000.0000000000176  #off by 2.3948e-12
>>> (a*a).sum()
1000.0000000000059  #off by 1.40948e-11
```

The `np.dot(a, a)` will be the more accurate of the two as it use approximately half the number of floating point roundings that the naive `(a*a).sum()` does.

A book by Nvidia has the following example for 4 digits of precision. `rn` stands for 4 round to the nearest 4 digits:

```
x = 1.0008
x2 = 1.00160064                    #    true value
rn(x2 − 1) = 1.6006 × 10−4         #    fused multiply-add
rn(rn(x2) − 1) = 1.6000 × 10−4     #    multiply, then add
```

Of course floating point numbers are not rounded to the 16th decimal place in base 10, but you get the idea.

Placing `np.dot(a,a)` in the above notation with some additional pseudo code:

```
out=0
for x in a:
    out=rn(x*x+out)   #Fused multiply add
```

While `(a*a).sum()` is:

```
arr=np.zeros(a.shape[0])   
for x in range(len(arr)):
    arr[x]=rn(a[x]*a[x])

out=0
for x in arr:
    out=rn(x+out)
```

From this its easy to see that the number is rounded twice as many times using `(a*a).sum()` compared to `np.dot(a,a)`. These small differences summed can change the answer minutely. Additional exmaples can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Comment: If numpy is using an optimized blas for the user machine, and he has a processor which has fma. One should not make too many assumptions based on "the blas *can* do that..."

Comment: Yes, even for Intel Ivy Bridge `a+b*c` compiles to `mulss` followed by `addss`.

Comment: Did you add adequate compiler options? (like -march=core-avx2 -mavx -mfma... with gcc)

Comment: Hum that is interesting, I had believed FMA was more ubiquitous then it is- the market does appear to be headed in that direction however.