# Numpy floating point rounding errors

Tags: python, numpy, precision

While searching for some numpy stuff, I came across a question discussing the rounding accuracy of numpy.dot():

[Numpy: Difference between dot(a,b) and (a*b).sum()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092984/numpy-difference-between-dota-b-and-ab-sum)

Since I happen to have two (different) Computers with Haswell-CPUs sitting on my desk, that should provide FMAand everything, I thought I'd test the example given by Ophion in the first answer, and I got a result that somewhat surprised me:

After updating/installing/fixing lapack/blas/atlas/numpy, I get the following on both machines:

```
>>> a = np.ones(1000, dtype=np.float128)+1e-14
>>> (a*a).sum()
1000.0000000000199999
>>> np.dot(a,a)
1000.0000000000199948

>>> a = np.ones(1000, dtype=np.float64)+1e-14
>>> (a*a).sum()
1000.0000000000198
>>> np.dot(a,a)
1000.0000000000176
```

So the standard multiplication + sum() is more precise than np.dot(). timeit however confirmed that the .dot() version is faster (but not much) for both float64 and float128.

Can anyone provide an explanation for this?

edit: I accidentally deleted the info on numpy versions: same results for 1.9.0 and 1.9.3 with python 3.4.0 and 3.4.1.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I only get this discrepancy on NumPy 1.9.2, and not NumPy 1.8.2.

Both use the blas + lapack (not atlas).

With NumPy 1.8.2, the results are identical with dot and sum, suggesting identical rounding events, on NumPy 1.9.2, multiplication + sum() is more precise.

Comment: See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#better-numerical-stability-for-sum-in-some-cases

Comment: Also https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3685, which is where the change in `sum` was implemented.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that ATLAS uses FMA? I know the latest MKL does, should be an interesting comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they recently added a special [Pairwise Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation) to `ndarray.sum` for improved numerical stability.

From [PR 3685](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3685), this affects:

```
all add.reduce calls that go over float_add with IS_BINARY_REDUCE true
so this also improves mean/std/var and anything else that uses sum.
```

See [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3685/files#diff-eb6ddd50e74f51bd4bceae1d17bfe4dcR1375) for code changes.

Comment: A "divide and conquer" algorithm. Yes, that would make sense, thanks.

Comment: Does this mean we are actually better of using alternative strategies to compute matrices than integrated functions? That would be ironic, given that numpy purposes is to ease scientific work.