# Calculate moments (mean, variance) of distribution in python

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I have two arrays. x is the independent variable, and counts is the number of counts of x occurring, like a histogram. I know I can calculate the mean by defining a function:

```
def mean(x,counts):
    return np.sum(x*counts) / np.sum(counts)
```

Is there a general function I can use to calculate each moment from the distribution defined by x and counts? I would also like to compute the variance.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413522/weighted-standard-deviation-in-numpy

Comment: (your function `mean` could also be written `np.average(x, weights=counts)`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the [`moment` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.moment.html#scipy.stats.moment) from `scipy`.  It calculates the n-th *central* moment of your data.

You could also define your own function, which could look something like this:

```
def nmoment(x, counts, c, n):
    return np.sum(counts*(x-c)**n) / np.sum(counts)
```

In that function, `c` is meant to be the point around which the moment is taken, and n is the order.  So to get the variance you could do `nmoment(x, counts, np.average(x, weights=counts), 2)`.

Comment: What is `counts`? shouldn't moment be `np.mean((x-c)^n)`?

Comment: @Lee, this is really a question for the OP as I just recapitulated their usage of `counts`.  It seems like its essentially a weight vector that says how much to weight each data point.

Answer (score 2):

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy import stats
stats.moment(counts, moment = 2) #variance
```

stats.moment returns nth central moment.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy supports order statistics now

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.statistics.html

- `np.average`
- `np.std`
- `np.var`
  etc