# Python - calculate weighted rolling standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas, standard-deviation

I have minute by minute a panda dataframe df. I'm looking to apply weighting to Return and compute a rolling weighted standard deviation, with window = 10. I can calculate non-weighted std, annualized with:

```
df_spy['10mVol'] = df_spy['Return'].rolling(center=False,window=10).std()*(1440*252)**(0.5)*100
```

There is another question asking for weighted std in Numpy, but i'm curious on the rolling weighted stdev. ([Weighted standard deviation in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413522/weighted-standard-deviation-in-numpy?rq=1))

The formula for calculating weighted standard deviation is:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320441/standard-deviation-of-the-weighted-mean

```
weighting   Midpoint   Return      10mVol   Weighted
0.2         215.6700    NaN         NaN      NaN
0.8         215.8400    -0.000788   NaN     -0.000630
0.8         216.0600    -0.001019   NaN     -0.000815
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the chained function after the `rolling` method is a function that takes an array and gives a number. That function is calculated for each window. So, if we have a function that calculates the weighted-std, we can use it with a lambda function to get the rolling-weighted-std. Here is my take. (I hope I didn't make a mistake with weighted-std calculation you provided)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def weighted_std(values, weights):
    # For simplicity, assume len(values) == len(weights)
    # assume all weights > 0
    sum_of_weights = np.sum(weights)
    weighted_average = np.sum(values * weights) / sum_of_weights
    n = len(weights)
    numerator = np.sum(n * weights * (values - weighted_average) ** 2.0)
    denominator = (n - 1) * sum_of_weights
    weighted_std = np.sqrt(numerator / denominator)
    return weighted_std


def rolling_std(s, weights):
    window_size = len(weights)
    return s.rolling(center=False, window=window_size).apply(lambda win: weighted_std(win, weights))

s = pd.Series(np.random.random([10]))  # generate random data
w = np.array([1., 3., 5.])  # choose weights
print(s.values)
print(rolling_std(s, w).values)
```

Example output:

```
[ 0.08101966  0.57133241  0.29491028  0.25139964  0.26151065  0.45768199
  0.94459935  0.21534497  0.35999294  0.60242746]
[        nan         nan  0.19701963  0.11936639  0.01539041  0.12097725
  0.33346742  0.40784167  0.25884732  0.17709334]
```

Here `lambda win: weighted_std(win, weights)` is a function that takes an array as an input and returns a number.

Comment: thanks for the quick feedback. when i changed the window_size to something shorter than len(weights), the function outputs  operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5864,) (10,). Otherwise it outputs NaN for all values.