# Calculate weighted statistical moments in Python

Tags: numpy, scipy, skew, kurtosis, code-statistics

I've been looking for a function or package that would allow me to calculate the skew and kurtosis of a distribution in a weighted way, as I have histogram data.

For instance I have the data

```py
import numpy as np

np.array([[1, 2],
          [2, 5],
          [3, 6],
          [4,12],
          [5, 1])
```

where the first column `[1,2,3,4,5]` are the values and the second column `[2,5,6,12,1]` are the frequencies of the values.

I have found out how to do the first two moments (mean, standard deviation) in a weighted way using the `weighted_avg_and_std` function specified in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413522/weighted-standard-deviation-in-numpy), but I was not quite sure how I could extend this to both the skew and kurtosis, or even the nth statistical moment.

I have found the definitions themselves [here](http://www.nematrian.com/WeightedMomentsAndCumulants) and could manually write functions to implement this from scratch, but before I go and do that I was wondering if there were any existing packages or functions that might be able to do this.

Thanks

EDIT:
I figured it out, the following code works (please note that this is for *population* moments)

```py
skewnewss = np.average(((values-average)/np.sqrt(variance))**3, weights=weights)
```

and

```py
kurtosis=np.average(((values-average)/np.sqrt(variance))**4-3, weights=weights)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have already listed all the ingredients that you need, following the formulas in the link you provided:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2],[2,5],[3,6],[4,12],[5,1]])
values, weights = a.T

def n_weighted_moment(values, weights, n):

    assert n>0 & (values.shape == weights.shape)
    w_avg = np.average(values, weights = weights)
    w_var = np.sum(weights * (values - w_avg)**2)/np.sum(weights)

    if n==1:
        return w_avg
    elif n==2:
        return w_var
    else:
        w_std = np.sqrt(w_var)
        return np.sum(weights * ((values - w_avg)/w_std)**n)/np.sum(weights)
              #Same as np.average(((values - w_avg)/w_std)**n, weights=weights)
```

Which results in:

```py
for n in range(1,5):
    print(f'Moment {n} value is {n_weighted_moment(values, weights, n)}')

Moment 1 value is 3.1923076923076925
Moment 2 value is 1.0784023668639053
Moment 3 value is -0.5962505715592139
Moment 4 value is 2.384432138280637
```

Notice that while you are calculating the *excess kurtosis*, the formula implemented for a generic n-moment doesn't account for that.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [here](http://www.ccgalberta.com/pygeostat/statistics.html#weighted-statistics)

Here is the code

```
def weighted_mean(var, wts):
    """Calculates the weighted mean"""
    return np.average(var, weights=wts)


def weighted_variance(var, wts):
    """Calculates the weighted variance"""
    return np.average((var - weighted_mean(var, wts))**2, weights=wts)


def weighted_skew(var, wts):
    """Calculates the weighted skewness"""
    return (np.average((var - weighted_mean(var, wts))**3, weights=wts) /
            weighted_variance(var, wts)**(1.5))

def weighted_kurtosis(var, wts):
    """Calculates the weighted skewness"""
    return (np.average((var - weighted_mean(var, wts))**4, weights=wts) /
            weighted_variance(var, wts)**(2))
```